# Android Studios CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android-studio

If I use a one minute interval as shown below, the speech function doesn't work the second time it's called. If I use a shorter, ie 30 second interval, then it works as intended. I think this has something to do with the tts engine not being ready. Any ideas? I've tested this with longer examples and the problem seems to be somewhere in the if statement. For example, I've tried 4 minute examples and it will say "4 minutes remain, 3 minutes remain, 2 minutes remain, ..., Countdown Complete".

```
    new CountDownTimer(120000, **60000**) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long minutesLeft = (((millisUntilFinished + 60000) / 1000) / 60);
            if (minutesLeft==1){
                speech(minutesLeft + " minute remains");
            } else{
                speech(minutesLeft + "minutes remain");
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            speech("Countdown Complete");
        }
    }.start();

    private void speech(String toSpeak) {
    float pitch, speed;
    pitch=1;
    speed=1;
    engine.setPitch(pitch);
    engine.setSpeechRate(speed);
    engine.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I had to do was add an extra half second to my total time. So changing 120000 to 120500 fixed the problem.